# Change button login to logout after login o navbar bootstrap

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3, frameworks

I try to make the login button at bootstrap navbar , but I find it difficult when I try after login and then enter the login button turns into logout ? is there who can help me

```
<li class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/login" class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle collapsed">Login</a>   
</li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Codeigniter 3

When you have logged on in the success part of login function you should create some session userdata where you could store some usernames or any data you need. Then on the view you should be able to use session like below

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('username') == TRUE) {?>

    <li class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('login/logout'); ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle collapsed">logout</a>   
    </li>   

<?php } else { ?>

    <li class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('login/login'); ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle collapsed">Login</a>   
    </li>   

<?php } ?>
```

On your logout function unset or destroy sessions.

Also on your base_url() you may need to include the index.php

```
<?php echo base_url('index.php/login/login'); ?>
<?php echo base_url('index.php/login/logout'); ?>
```

When you create session you need encryption key http://randomkeygen.com/ for codeigniter on application/config/config.php around **line 313** And also once you have got encryption key autoload session.

Setting Session data http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

```
$newdata = array(
        'username'  => 'johndoe',
        'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
        'logged_in' => TRUE
);

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

Sample Controller

```
<?php 

class Login extends CI_Controller {

   public function index() {
      $this->login();
   }

    public function login() {
       $this->load->library('form_validation');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

       if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('login_view');

       } else {

            $newdata = array(
               'username'  => $this->input->post('username'),
               'logged_in' => TRUE
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

            redirect('success-controller');
       }
    }

    public function logout() {
       // Also unset your user data here

       redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Form Validation Userguide

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Autoload

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('array', 'date', 'file', 'form', 'html', 'url');
```

Comment: you are missing `}` to end your `else` part

Comment: @wolfgang1983 , nice but how i create session?
`<?php if ($this->session->userdata('username') == TRUE) {?>
`

Comment: @irwanDwiyanto here is the user guide  link on sessions http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html and form_validation http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: @irwanDwiyanto I put a sample login controller on. I also would look into php pass word http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php when creating pass word and password verify for checking password http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: @wolfgang1983 , thanks for the advice , I 'm building a website but weak in php